# Sufficiency of properly discontinuous action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

We know that if $M$ is a topological space and $G$ a group action on $M$ then we say that the action is properly discontinuous if for all $x\in M$ there is $U \ni x$ such that for every $g\neq e \in G$, $gU \cap U = \emptyset.$

So, I was asked to show that a certain action is properly discontinuous. My friend said that is enough to show that for every $x \in M$ then $gx \neq x.$ Is this true? Why?

What does mean in practice mean that $gU \cap U = \emptyset$? It does mean in fact that $gx \neq x$ for all $x$, but, to show that $gx\neq x \forall x \in U$ does not necessarily implies that $gU \cap U = \emptyset$, right?

For example, I could have $x,y \in U$ such that $gx = y.$ Or this does not occur?

Thanks

Comment: It's not sufficient. A trivial counterexample is an indiscrete space, then $gU = U$ for every neighbourhod of $x$, since the only neighbourhood of $x$ is the whole space. If we only consider actions on Hausdorff spaces, it's still not sufficient without further conditions, since there may be a sequence $(g_n)$ in $G$ with $g_n x \to x$ and $g_n x \neq x$ for all $n$. It is sufficient if the group is finite and the space Hausdorff.

Comment: Tell your friend that she/he is mistaken. As another example consider $G=M={\mathbb R}$ where $G$ acts on $M$ by binary group operation $(g,m)\mapsto g+m$.